# Coding an interface where user selects date reoccurnace

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, frequency, frequency-distribution

I need to create an interface where a user needs to select how many times his magizine/newspaper gets distributed. Some magazines/newspapers get distributed

- Several times a week.
- Several times a a month: --either by day (e.g. every second tuesday) or by date (e.g. on the 1st, 10th and 28th)
- Several times a year.

Once the frequency has been chosen, I need to add additional information to each frequency item. e.g. if the user chose weekly on Mondays and Fridays, I need to add additional information for Monday and separate information for Friday.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Or where I can read more or get some examples?

I'm using PHP and javascript/jquery for this application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to ask the end user a series of questions, and use jquery to display to next set of questions for the next set of results etc